# Get index of td elements in table using Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a table.. It's in jade templating format so i've not created a jsfiddle for it.

Anyhow, the user clicks a button within the table and this toggles a class which displays all the information to do with that table.

The user clicks and this code gets executed:

```
$(function() {
  $('.information-button').click(function() {
    detailsPopup(this);
  });
});
```

The onclick calls the function below:

```
function detailsPopup(el) {
//   $(el).find("td").each(function(index){
//    var bookingData = $(this).html();
// })
array1.indexOf(td [ fromIndex])
  console.log($(el));
  $(".details--info, .overlay--contain").toggle('600');
}
```

The problem i'm having, is I need to loop through all the td elements of the booking, grab the index and pass it through the onclick event. So when I toggle the class that displays the information, it only shows the information for that table cell.

Anyone know how I can achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: `array1.indexOf($(el).index())`

Comment: can you share the html sample

Comment: provide html for better answer

Comment: index of `td` with respect to what

Comment: Sorry, my table is generated using javascript in my index.jade file so I didn't include it

Comment: You can recreate a cut-down version of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [Index](http://api.jquery.com/index/) in jquery.

select parent and get index number.

i.e:

```
$(el).closest('tr').index();
```